# How to create a hastebin with java

Tags: java

I need to create a hastebin paste in java, but I don't know how.
I tried this

```
public static String paste(String content) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://hasteb.in/documents");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) con;
        http.addRequestProperty("data", content);
        http.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        http.setDoOutput(true);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(http.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        StringBuilder entirePage = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            entirePage.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();
        if (!(entirePage.toString().contains("\"key\":\""))) {
            return "UNKNOWN";
        }
        return "https://hasteb.in/"+entirePage.toString().split("\"key\":\"")[1].split("\",")[0];
    }
```

But it does not work.
Error is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value`
Any help?

Comment: "But it does not work" What happening? Do you have any error?

Comment: If I were to guess I'd say `http.addRequestProperty("data", content);` is the problematic line here. You're adding a HTTP header named data (probably with invalid characters), while I think you meant to set the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a POST request using `HttpURLConnection` you need to write the request body using the provided `OutputStream` functionality rather than setting a HTTP header named "data":

```
try (OutputStream out = http.getOutputStream()) {
  out.write(content.getBytes());
  out.flush();
}
```

This needs to happen BEFORE you start reading from the `InputStream` (and I would suggest using try-with-resources for that as well).